# Meaning of === operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Example as:

```
if (c === 0){
   //
}
```

What is the meaning of === here in above ex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2):

It checks that `c` is equal to the *number* `0`. `===` is the strict equality operator. It does not attempt to type coerce the operands.

For example:

```
0 == false; //true (false coerces to 0)
0 === false; //false (no type coercion)
```

Comment: in other words, it check the values *and* the type

Comment: @Joseph - Yeah that might have been a simpler way to put it :)

Comment: and to clarify a little more, "0" === "0" is true

Comment: @Steve - I think that goes without saying... they are both strings.

Comment: I know, but it was just to give an example that had a true result.  If the person is asking the question, why not give a complete answer?

Answer (score 2):

`a == b` means that `a` equals `b`

`a === b`  means that `a` equals `b` and their **types** are the same

Answer (score 1):

This is the strict equal operator and only returns a Boolean true if both the operands are equal and of the same type. Assume these:

```
a = 2
b = 4
```

These next examples return true:

```
a === 2 
b === 4
```

There is also a reverse of this operator: !==  This is the strict not equal operator and only returns a value of true if both the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type. The following examples return a Boolean true:

```
a !== b 
a !== "2" 
4 !== '4'
```

All quoted from here:
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var y = 0;
        if(y == "0"){
            document.write("== '0' True <br/>");
        }
        else{
            document.write("== '0' False <br/>");
        }

        if(y == 0){
            document.write("== 0 Number is True <br/>");
        }
        else{
            document.write("== 0 Number False <br/>");
        }

        if( y === 0){
            document.write("=== 0 Number is True <br/>");
        }
        else{
            document.write("=== 0 Number is False <br/>");
        }

        if(y === "0"){
            document.write("=== 0 is True <br/>");
        }
        else{
            document.write("=== 0 is False<br/>");
        }
    </script>
```

If the right value is `0` , you will get

```
== '0' True
== 0 Number is True
=== 0 Number  is True
=== 0 is False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator only checks for equivalence of two values while the `===` operator goes an additional step and also asserts that the types of the two values are the same.

```
2 == "2" // true
```

While:

```
2 === "2" // false
```